# Is there any way to be notified when sqlite tables update?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, fmdb

I am developing an iOS app that uses sqlite database with the help of `FMDB`. I used to work with `Core Data`, but it was very slow with 5000 items insert at a time. `FMDB` with transactions make such inserts much more faster!

Also I need some mechanism that can notify my view controllers when some items from sqlite table are updated. `NSFetchedResultsController` was my solution, but since I use `FMDB` I can no longer use `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Is there any way to be notified when sqlite tables update?

Comment: Does your app really spend the majority of its time doing inserts?

Comment: I am testing on 2500 items delete + insert. It takes 10-12 seconds. FMDB makes delete + insert in 0.5-0.7 seconds. Some users have up to 5000-6000 items.

Comment: Yes, but how often are they going to be inserting and deleting the entire set?   If they are importing ONCE and then incrementally updating/scanning over time, you are giving up a TON of functionality for a one time operation.  If they are importing and deleting that much data as their main operation, it may be justified.

Comment: Also, did you use instruments to find out why and change batching to see how it affects performance?

Comment: You'll have to roll your own. That's part of what Core Data does for you.

Comment: It's not the entire set. It's just one of them. User can open dozens  of different sets every minute while searching. And every time I need to sync each set with set of downloaded items.

Comment: I take it that no two users databases are the same?   If they were, then you could just download pre-populated databases.   If you have a subscription model, you could manage multiple persistent stores.   2 orders of magnitude performance difference sounds like you haven't optimized the CoreData delete/insert process correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been searching for a while and found a solution. I wonder why I haven't found it earlier.

My choice now is [YapDatabase](https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase/wiki/What-is-YapDatabase). I don't know about its weaknesses but there are so many great things about this library:

- **Regularly updated**. Has more then 1000 commits! Wow!
- It's a **key/value store**. I'm just saving my NSDictionaries. No more data models and headaches.
- **Perfomance** is great. I have compared to Core Data delete + insert speed.
- And the most great thing is "**Views**":

> **Views** allow you Sort, Group & Filter your data. Perfect for
>   tableViews, collectionViews, and more. And they even provide
>   NSFetchedResultsController style updates to make it easy to animate
>   changes to your tableViews/collectionViews.

Answer (score 0):

My advice to you is to revert back to Core Data. You should address the insert performance issue rather than dropping down to the database level and having to revisit all kinds of far more complicated mechanisms of your data model setup. Your specific issue is a case in point.

To optimize the speed of inserts refer to the numerous helpful SOF answers. As has been pointed out, finding the right **batch size** for your data type is key here.

Regardless of your optimizations, however, you can leverage the Core Data framework to perform these intensive operations **in the background**. This would not impact the usability of your app, presumably even less than your 0.7 seconds inserts with FMDB.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have changed my mind and abandoned FMDB usage. But I decided to give YapDatabase a try.