# What is the best way to store dynamically changing data locally on iOS today?

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, sqlite, local-storage

My goal is to build a simple iOS app using Swift that will aggregate various types of data, from numerous sources, all with changing schema over time. It would also need to be able to handle something along the lines of 10’s of thousands of records to be saved. I am new to iOS programming when it comes to storing data locally. Obviously there are things like Local Storage and SQLite that could help me do this, but it seems like what I want is something more like a local MongoDB-like store that has been implemented in Swift. Is this what I should be looking for (because at this moment I have not found anything like this) or is there something I am missing or should be aware of in order to accomplish this?

Comment: You should look into CoreData.https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html

Comment: I have read a little about Core Data, but I thought you had to know the schema of the data beforehand. I would ideally like to throw my data into collections that are schema-less like MongoDB.

Comment: You can try `YapDatabase`, it is a key-value store build on top of SQLite. Any `NSObject` conforming to `NSCoding` can be saved. I have chosen it for some projects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35305484/1292099 P.S. working with it on `Swift` is okay.

Comment: This is quite a complex subject.  If your schema is going to vary over time (assuming the app doesn't update to take account of it) then you are going to have to create some kind of custom layer on top of your data storage.  For a start something has to tell the app the current schema and then that is used to store the data in a generic structure in the storage.  As for the storage type Core Data could still be used or SQLite.

Comment: Awesome and thank you for your responses. I think I have some backend organization to think out before I move any further!